# Connect to a (git) project: Include project name in suggested local path

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017

Is there a way to have VS put TFS project name> automatically in the suggested local path?

As of now, the suggested path is `<default path>\<repo name>`, I want it `<default path>\<TFS project name>\<repo name>`.

Current functionality means that if I clone several repos from different team projects, the folders are mixed with eachother. I'd like the extra level to seperate repos into TFS team projects, and we have to do this manually as of now.

Also, is there no way of setting the default path before cloning the first repo? When no repo has been cloned, the Settings doesn't include Git settings.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1 : Is there a way to have VS put TFS project name> automatically in the
>   suggested local path?

**No way to do it once and for all**.

That means if you have multiple repositories in one team project, then you can set the `Default Repository Location` which including the `Team Project name` in it. Reference below screenshot.

But if you want to switch to another team project, then you have to reset the `Default Repository Location` including the new team project name in it.

e.g.: `D:\LC-WS\GitRepos\Git-Scrum`  (`Git-Scrum` is the team project name here)

Thus, the repositories will be cloned to `D:\LC-WS\GitRepos\Git-Scrum\RepoName`

> Q2 : Also, is there no way of setting the default path before cloning the
>   first repo? When no repo has been cloned, the Settings doesn't include
>   Git settings.

You have to **connect to the Git Team Project** first, you can see the `Settings` once you connected to team project.

[image]

Comment: Okay, thanks! Not much uplifting there. We are a small developer team and thus we cover all areas of the product, but in TFS we have the code in several teams and several repositories. Is this bad? We actually also had the work items in several teams, but this was living hell - now all work items is in the same team/project/board with tags determining what part of the product it belongs. This actually works pretty good.

Comment: @SvendK Yeah, you can manage the source code in several repositories as the project grows. However if the source codes belong to component features of the same project, then you can try using [Branches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/repos/git/git-branching-guidance?view=vsts) instead of separated repository, thus you can merge to main when everything is ready, it's more convenient when building in TFS.  You can set area paths to determine what shows up on your team's backlog and what work items your team is responsible for. However work item with Tags is also good experience.

Comment: @SvendK If the answer helps? If that answered your question you could Accept it as an Answer, This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread. :)

Comment: Sorry! Somehow I moved on and didn't get to mark it as an answer. Maybe I hoped for someone else to give me another answer... :). Our product consist of various projects: a main WinForms app, a newer version main WPF app, several other smaller WinForms apps, quite a few "components" in the form off DLL projects/Nuget, an MVC web site and several API sites (SOAP + Web API) - and all team members work in all projects. We need the layering, but maybe teams is not correct.

Comment: Nevertheless, I think it would be nice to have <tags> to put in the default path or checkboxes to "include team folder" in the path. I must submit a couple of UserVoice items to Microsoft for this.